# Is there a better way to parse external .csv data so iPad can load page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a web app that needs to run locally on an iPad2. I have a 20MB .csv file with a zip code database for North America. Whenever I try to parse the data, the iPad browser (Safari, Chrome, Opera) simply crashes as I assume I'm crushing it's little 512MB of RAM. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
function readZipCodes() {
     var zipCodes = [];
     $.ajax({
         url: 'data/ZipCodeDatabase.csv',
         contentType: "text/csv",
         async: false,
         success: function(text) {
             zipCodes = text.split("\n");
         }
     });
     return zipCodes;
 }
```

I have not been able to get the browser to read the data without the `async: false`

How can I fix it so it works on the iPad?

Comment: The `split` I probably causing your problem. Try doing it server-side;  convert your file to JSON then send it to the client.

Comment: Unfortunately, there app must run 100% on the iPad. It runs in a location with no network access.

Comment: Are you able to convert the csv file to a json file and load that? Might be easier to deal with.

Comment: I considered it, but it's 955 thousand lines....

Comment: I fixed it. I found a MUCH smaller zip code database.